# captcha field does not work for my current js script

Tags: javascript, captcha, imacros

I am trying to pypass the captcha for a form & it worked before & now they have changed some image bypass IDs.

form captcha elements as per below.
[form elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF11m.png)

and the script which I wrote is as below

```
code+='ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER={{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}} FILE=image.jpg WAIT=YES'+newline;
        code+='TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:*data:image* CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEPICTUREAS'+newline;       
        code+='TAB OPEN'+newline;
        code+='TAB T=2'+newline;
        code+='URL GOTO=http://api.dbcapi.me/decaptcher?function=picture2&print_format=html'+newline;
        code+='TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:username CONTENT=nadunpeushan2'+newline;
        code+='TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=nadun123'+newline;
        code+='TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:pict CONTENT={{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}}\\image.jpg'+newline;
        code+='TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=TYPE:submit'+newline;
        code+='TAG POS=6 TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT'+newline;
        code+='SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}'+newline;
        code+='TAB CLOSE'+newline;
```

the problem is in this section

```
code+='TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:*data:image*
```

need to what exactly would be for TYPE & ATTR

Great help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
code+='TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=CLASS:photo&&SRC:blob* CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEPICTUREAS'+newline;
```